# Popup or Child window in Java Script

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Am developing a web application using phonegap. There is one issue where i need to bring a  Child window on top of main window more like a popup. The child window is basically a notepad(textarea).

I tried to use `onClick=window.open` but it dint work in **android emulator**. And there is an api for phonegap which is **loadurl** .. but it actually takes to the next page (full screen) but not as an popup.

Could use ur inputs on `How to create a popup window in javascript which works in android emulator`

Thanks
Thilak

Answer (score 0):

use http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/

u can download  from here http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/install.html